# Laravel export to excel - download issue

Tags: excel, laravel, download, export

I can't generate xlsx file. I'am using maatwebsite/excel 3.1. I have installed it via this:

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

I've added `'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,` to Aliases and `Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,` to providers.

I have structure of project like ProjectName->app->Exports.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Order;
use App\Status;
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class ActiveOrderExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Status::all();
    }
}
```

In repository I have function excel, also with these inclusions:

```
use App\Exports\ActiveOrderExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
```

```
public function excel()
    {
       return Excel::download(new ActiveOrderExport(), 'activeOrders.xlsx');
    }
```

Route:`Route::get('/export_excel', 'HomeController@excel')->name('admin.export_excel.excel');`

Home Controller:

```
    {
        $this->AOrepository->excel();
        //return back();
    }
```

My problem is that no error is shown, only blank page. No download is executed in the browser.
I've watched several tutorials, I haven't noticed any important diffrence among the codes.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Try adding a return before `$this->AOrepository->excel();`

Comment: You are perfect, it helped, thank you very much.